# Operations on Python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, operators

Why does the following code output **8**?

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
print(lst[lst[4]])
```

**Output: 8**

Comment: `list[4]` = ***5*** (list index starts from ***0***). `list[5]` (= `[list[list[4]]`) = ***8***. Also don't name your variable `list`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list, example A = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70], then to access a specific element you must specify the **index** of that element. The index is basically the position of that element and python lists start at 0. So, if we wanted to get the element '10' in the list A, we would say A[0] because it is the first element. **Remember, the number you put in brackets is the position you are asking for**.

Now in your list, lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13], you are saying lst[lst[4]] where lst[4] == 5, but this 5 is getting passsed as the position. So lst[lst[4]] is the same as lst[5] which is equal to 8.

Comment: why if lst[4] == 5 and 5 is getting passed as the position?

Comment: @Z-CODE, here is the list: lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]. So if you start counting from zero lst[0] = 1; lst[1] = 1; lst[2] = 2; lst[3] = 3; lst[4] = 5. Number in brackets [] is the positon, and the number after the = sign is the value

Answer (score 0):

Break it down

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

x = lst[4] # 5
y = lst[lst[4]] # lst[5]
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

This took me a bit, but I had to write it out. I'm a visual learner.
*solve from inner part out*

**Our code to solve:**

lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

print(lst[lst[4]])

**step 1:**

print(lst[lst[4]]) = print(lst[5])

**This is because 5 is in the lst[4] or 4th index**

**Then:**

print(lst[5]) = 8

**because 8 is in the 5th index.**